# .tmux.conf not being read on Mac but being read on Linux?

Tags: linux, macos, tmux

I am trying to simply change the prefix key on my tmux setup from `C-b`, to `C-\`

On both my linux and Mac OS X computers I have a file named `.tmux.conf` file in `~/`

All of the settings in the file are applied on my linux system, however none of them are applied on my Mac and I am wondering if anyone knows why this might be?

This is my `.tmux.conf`:

```
# Set colors
set-option -g default-terminal "screen-256color"

# Set reload key to r
# bind r source-file ~/.tmux.conf

# Change prefix
unbind-key C-b
set -g prefix 'C-\'
bind-key 'C-\' send-prefix

# Count sessions start at 1
set -g base-index 1

# Set the title bar
set -g set-titles on
set -g set-titles-string '#(whoami) :: #h :: #(curl ipecho.net/plain;echo)'

# Set status bar
set -g status-utf8 on
set -g status-bg black
set -g status-fg white
set -g status-interval 5 
set -g status-left-length 90
set -g status-right-length 60
set -g status-left "#[fg=Green]#(whoami)#[fg=white]::#[fg=blue]#(hostname -s)#[fg=white]::#[fg=yellow]#(curl ipecho.net/plain;echo)"
set -g status-justify left
set -g status-right '#[fg=Cyan]#S #[fg=white]%a %d %b %R'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently you haven't started `tmux-server`, it's `tmux-server` that reads `~/.tmux.conf` file on startup, but not `tmux` session.

Try to kill all tmux sessions and restart the `tmux-server` e.g.

```
$ tmux kill-server
```

Alternatively try to reload `~/.tmux.conf` without restarting server like this

```
:source-file ~/.tmux.conf
```

Probably there are errors in configuration file.